# Option button linkedcell without blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first message and i'm sorry in advance for my English.
I added multiple option button to my worksheet and I wrote this code.

```
Dim btn As OptionButton
For Each btn In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
    btn.LinkedCell = btn.TopLeftCell.Offset(-4, 5).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)
Next btn
```

when i ran this code my worksheet it's going as follows.
[image]

What I want is that the option buttons linked cell without blank cells (etc:U1,U2,U3,U4,...)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At least you might give me a path which is what's wrong with my code. Because the trick is questions number are valuable and i need that allways same column but without space